# Stopping people from getting around my form validation by navigating elsewhere

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form that lets users edit item data in my database.I require every item to have an accompanying picture, so i validate the itempic with jQUery validation's required rule.

Currently, the user will select an item and generate the form containing the item details in the order Category> SubCategory>Item>Form generated.The user can then delete the existing item pic and replace it with a new one.However, because i am making the item pic a required item, he will be unable to submit the form without replacing the item pic he deleted with a new item pic.

This validation works perfectly with one exception.After deleting an item pic,if the user clicks on my navigation bar and goes somewhere else, he is able to skip bypass the validation completely.This leaves me with an item with no display pics, and leads to errors down the road when he loads the same form, as there is no display pic for the item.

Is there any way to prevent this?

PHP Form generation code (Extract):

```
//Input and preview for Display Pic
echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails' >";
    echo"<label for='BizEditItemFileDP'>Upload Image[DP] &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp(Max Size:2MB)</label>";
    echo"<input type='file' class='BizEditItemInput' id='BizEditItemFileDP' name='BizEditItemFileDP' />";
    echo"<input type='button' id=ImageCancelDP name=ImageCancelDP class='ImageCancelButton' value='Cancel'>";
    echo"<span></span>";
    echo"<br>";
    echo"<img id='ImagePreviewDP' name='ImagePreviewDP' class='ImagePreview' src=\"$dp\" > ";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id='ImagePreviewDPValidate' name='ImagePreviewDPValidate' value=\"$dp\" >";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id='DisplayDeleteItemID' name='DisplayDeleteItemID' value=$itemid>";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id='DisplayDeleteItemPicID' name='DisplayDeleteItemPicID' value=$dpid>";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id='DisplayDeleteFilePath' name='DisplayDeleteFilePath' value=$dpfilepath >";
    echo"<input type='button' id='DisplayDelete' name='DisplayDelete' class='ImageDeleteButton' value='Delete Picture'>";
    echo"<br>";
echo"</div>";
```

jQuery Validation(Extract):

```
ImagePreviewDPValidate:{
            required:true
        },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rethink your process, your current process cannot be fixed.

The problem is that you're allowing the first request to place the server-side record in an invalid state. You can't do that. There is no guarantee that the user will make a second request, and you can not force the issue with JavaScript. What if the just close the browser window, or walks away from the computer, or their Internet connection dies?

I would suggest changing the process so that a user may *replace* the image, which would happen in a single request to the server, as opposed to allowing them to delete the image and add a new one.

Comment: Yea that's what i figured.... and it seemed like a pretty decent idea at that point of time too.. Back to the drawing board i go then.